# Partial derivatives using chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $u = \frac{1}{y}[\phi(ax + y) + \phi(ax - y)]$, and $\phi$ is twice differentiable, show that,
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{a^2}{y^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$$

I arrived at the following::
$$LHS: \frac{a^2}{y}\left(\partial_x^2\phi(ax + y) + \partial_x^2\phi(ax - y)\right)$$
$$RHS: \frac{a^2}{y}\left(\partial_y^2\phi(ax + y) + \partial_y^2\phi(ax - y)\right)$$

After this how to show $LHS = RHS$?

Comment: Hint: what do you call $\partial_{x}^2\phi$ ? How does it relate to $\partial_{y}^2\phi$ ?

Comment: So basically, $\partial_x^2\phi = \partial_y^2\phi = \partial^2\phi$, right?